# Error while using kde function in GME

Tags: kernel-density, gme

Not sure if anyone else has encountered this error. I'm trying to use the kde command to generate some kernel density raster layers based on a shapefile. The error reads as follows:

`Error: An important error has occurred. Please include the information below if you submit a query about this error. The owner SID on a per-user subscription doesn't exist (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040207)`

After some research, it seems like people encounter this error through other programs, but I couldn't find any posts related to GME.

Here's the code:

`path<-"C:\Users\rweber\Desktop\GIS\"; uniquevalues(in="C:\Users\rweber\Desktop\GIS\BigAllSpr17.shp‌​", field="Tag__"); for (i in 1:length(uniquevalues)){ kde(in="C:\Users\reweber\Desktop\GIS\BigAllSpr17.shp", out=paste(path, uniquevalues[i], "_kde"), bandwidth="LSCV", cellsize=3, kernel="GAUSSIAN", ext="C:\Users\rweber\Documents\ArcGIS\BigCreek\BigCreekOutli‌​ne.shp", where=paste("Tag__='", uniquevalues[i],"'")); };`